# Can I use 'refrain' by itself, instead of 'refrain from doing that'?

Tags: word-usage

Is the following fine?

> What she did was bad. Please ask her to refrain.

I use 'refrain' this way, but I haven't heard anyone else that does, nor I could find confirmation on Google about using 'refrain' without the full 'refrain from doing that.'

Comment: You are more likely to receive helpful answers if you can edit this to give us more details about what you think might be the problem.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. And music has refrains, though that's another meaning;-)